# How to set two bindings in one expression

Tags: asp.net, binding

I have the following binding in my GridView:

```
Text='<%# Bind("FromDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'
```

I would take the format from the web config instead of hard coded value.

```
'<%$ AppSettings:EditDateFormat %>'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: doesn't it work to just assign `public string myFormat = AppSettings.EditDateFormat;` in your code-behind and do `Text='<%# Bind("FromDate", myFormat) %>'`?

Comment: @paolo: Before I go to any work arround, can't I put them together in one expression?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? this should work,

```
Text='<%# Bind("FromDate", "{0:" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EditDateFormat"]) +"}" %>'
```